# Changing opacity in form with trackbar in C# don't works, why?

Tags: c#, forms, opacity, smoothing, trackbar

I have (for fun) make a form in `C#`, with a `trackbar`.
I want to change the `Opacity` of the form with it, so I wrote this:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = trackBar1.Value;
    System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm.Opacity = trackBar1.Value;
    label2.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString();
}
```

When I start the program, the opacity will be 100% if the `trackbar` is in value 1 to 100, and if i drag the `trackbar` to 0, the form becomes fully transparant.

can you only get 100% `Opacity` or 0% `Opacity` when a form is started, or is what i want also possible?

Comment: I think opacity is a value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm.Opacity = ((double)(trackBar1.Value) /100.0)
```

You can have different degrees of opacity. For example 0.5 will give you 50% opacity.

Answer (score 4):

The value of `System.Windows.Forms.Form.Opacity` is between `0.0` and `1.0`, to get the percentage of the opacity you can multiply it with `100`, so `1` means `fully opaque` and `0` means `fully transparent`.

For the trackbar, you should convert its `Value` to the corresponding value between `0.0` and `1.0`, so you should do something like this:

```
yourForm.Opacity = (double)trackBar1.Value/trackBar1.Maximum;
```

Answer (score 3):

Divide the number by 100.  It should be a double between 0 and 1

```
((double)trackBar1.Value) / 100
```

Comment: Slight correction: opacity should be a `double` not a `decimal`. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx

Comment: Can't it be between 0 and 100? or is there just a "TRANSPARANT" or "NOT TRANSPARANT"

Comment: it is between 0 and 100, it's just a percentage - 25% = .25

Comment: Or did you mean `System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm.Opacity = trackBar1.Value/100;` ? That don't work also by the way.

Comment: that line should be exactly as AlexDev's answer has it

Answer (score -1):

private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
label1.Text =trackBar1.Value.ToString()+ "%";

```
        Opacity=trackBar1.Value / 100.00;
        
    }
```

Comment: a bit more explanation of your solution would be great, in that case it's simply because opacity is a value between 0 and 1.